# Using Mercurial locally with TFS Team Foundation Version Control Server Workspace

Tags: tfs, mercurial

At work we are using TFS Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) and the workspace is a server workspace (very large codebase). The limitations of our setup are that files checked out are locked for edit by other people. Also there is a culture of not committing until work is complete etc as many change-sets complicate merging later.

I am in no position to change the global rules or culture. I would like to locally setup a mercurial (hg) repo on my local machine. The idea is that I can work on my local copy make as many checkins to hg. When I am done I would like to bundle my changes into one changeset and send it off to the TFS location (also on my local machine). Then immediately checkin the changes to TFS server.
That way to the outside world I appear to checkout and then immediately checkin all of my code, only briefly locking the files changed. But locally in hg I get the full ability to make small checkins and work without worrying about locking files out for edit.

Somehow chain two version control systems, giving me the flexibility of HG locally, but continue using the global TFVC for final checkins.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use git-tf and the hg-git.  This was an intentional design decision when we built git-tf that this was a supported scenario.

That said...  this seems a bit...  icky.

You may want to write a few shell scripts to make this workflow a little bit easier.

But even with that, it's hard to imagine troubleshooting this when something inevitably goes wrong.

Comment: I am happy to drop Mercurial and use Git.

Comment: Does git-tf require an standalone installation of git?

Comment: No, but it does require a Java JRE.

Comment: Is there a way/guide on how to convert my existing checked out TFVC sources to use git without cloning the whole source code again?

Answer (score 1):

TFS doesn't have Mercurial support, but apparently does have Git support.
You can use the hg-git plugin to access TFS this way.

More details about the lack of support:

- https://hglabhq.com/blog/2014/1/17/mercurial-support-in-tfs-declined
- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3607357-add-mercurial-support-to-team-foundation-server

Comment: I cannot change the version control system used on server, which is TFVC, not git. I can only control what happens on my local machine.